# Equivalant of this gradient code in ie css filter

Tags: javascript, css, filter, gradient

i need an  equivalent or an alternative for this code in internet explorer using the filter method

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , rgb(132, 133, 132) 0%, rgb(35, 35, 35) 49%, rgb(104, 104, 104) 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
```

the most important thing in the code is the points ( 0% - 49% - 100% )
i believe that the filter method  doesn't have points and doesn't accpect more than two parms for the colors ,

Is there a way to do it in filter or a javascript script for that ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#0000FF', EndColorStr='#000000')"
```

Comment: I used to get the 010 button (to type in code snippet) on the top of my textarea but it has magically now disappeared. How do I get it back?

Comment: Don't know.  You can just indent 4 spaces (or highlight and press ctrl+k)

Answer (score 1):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28VS.85%29.aspx

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(sProperties);
```